# Qt Creator Cannot Compile Python Project

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-creator

i just installed Qt creator  and when i created a qt for python project with ui but when i try to
compile it i get this error at application output

Cannot execute "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified

i check the path there is no python.exe in that location

what should i do ???

[image]

i reinstalled the qt creator still i get the same error

Comment: What do you mean by "compile it"?

Comment: @musicamante when i try to run the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you controlled your python path in  Projects - Build steps?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).